# How to spawn a gpg child process from a daemon in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, child-process, gnupg

I can spawn a gpg child process and decrypt a file normally if I just run the app normally.

/app.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function decrypt() {
    var gpg = spawn('gpg', ['--no-use-agent', '--passphrase', 'My Passphrase', './test.pdf.asc']);

    gpg.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log(code); // code == 0
    });
}

decrypt();
```

run the app.js as regular process and can decrypt the file

```
node app.js
```

However, when I try to run the app.js as daemon using pm2, upstart, etc... I got the error code (2) and could not decrypt the file
run the app.js a a daemon

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: Since you pass `/test.pdf.asc`, is the file literally at the root of the filesystem?

Comment: Its a typo "./test.pdf.acs"

Comment: Important typo, that argument is probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know `pm2` well, but it is likely that your node process is starting with a different working directory, so when it tries to resolve your relative file path, it resolves to a different place.

Comment: Thank you loganfsmyth. It also did not work if I added the options parameter ({cwd: my_cwd}) in the spawn function. So we can safely eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Also, the same thing happens if I use upstart and/or forever.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(process.cwd())` or `require('path').resolve('./test.pdf.asc')` in `decrypt()` in the two different cases?

Comment: Thank for your help loganfsmyth. I already found the solution. Gpg is always expected to run interactively. So I need a flag '--no-tty'.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Node.js issue. It is related to gnupg tool. In order to run gpg from calling it in your codes or as a cron job, you need a flag '--no-tty'.